# What is about in book Bhamati?

Tags: scripture

Vachaspati Mishra took many years to create this book without taking care of his routine life like eat, sleep, drink etc. During this time his wife(Bhamati) kept his taken care. At last, when completed the book, He forgot his wife.

I just want to know brief detail about this book if possible.

Comment: You can some info from here: https://www.advaita-vedanta.org//avhp/bhavir.html